# Multiple instances of Livedata observers

Tags: android, reactive-programming, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I am struggling to find a solution for calling a livedata observer multiple times in one activity and not creating multiple instances of it, this leads to the problem when the database changes I got callbacks from all the instances.

ViewModel

```
public class RatingsViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private RatingsRepository ratingsRepository;
private LiveData<List<Rating>> ratingsList;

public RatingsViewModel(Application application) {
    super(application);
    ratingsRepository = new RatingsRepository(application);

}

public LiveData<List<Rating>> getRatingsByDate(LocalDate date) {
    ratingsList = ratingsRepository.getActivitiesByDate(date);
    return ratingsList;
}
```

Activity

```
private void getRatingsByDate(LocalDate date) {
    ratingsViewModel.getRatingsByDate(date).observe(this, activities -> {
        // list populating stuff
    });
}
```

I tried calling hasObserver() but it returns false so I cannot remove the observers.

Comment: I dont understand on thing, why are you observing in a method and passing date?. Create a setter in your viewmodel and pass the date there and and database gives the result which you can observe in the OnCreate() of your activity

Comment: @PrashanthVerma The date is dynamic when the user clicks on the date it shows those data, so you have to make a call with the new date. I dont understand your solution with the setter in viewmodel.

Comment: see `android.arch.lifecycle.Transformations` utility class

Comment: Let me get this straight. There is date that is selected by user you need get that date and search in DB and show it in the screen that's it right.!?

Comment: @pskink Yeah thanks a lot, that a different approach as the other answer. I check which is a better approach.

Comment: read [Transform LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#transform_livedata) section carefully - in particular pay attention from `"Similar to map(), applies a function to the value stored in the LiveData object and unwraps and dispatches the result downstream"`

Comment: @pskink Thanks, I read the documentation and it was useful.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like following (in Kotlin but should be easily translatable in to Java if needed)

```
val dateLiveData: MutableLiveData<Date> = MutableLiveData()

val ratingsList = MediatorLiveData<List<Rating>>().apply {
    this.addSource(dateLiveData) {
        this.value = ratingsRepository.getActivitiesByDate(dateLiveData.value)
    }
}

fun setDate(date: Date) {
    dateLiveData.value = date
}
```

You'd call `observe` from `onCreate()` for example in your activity/fragment and then call `setDate()` when that value changes.

Comment: So the logic here is to observe the parameter of an observer?, Thanks.

Comment: You would call for example `ratingsViewModel.ratingsList.observe()` (or perhaps through getter for `ratingsList`) ....and then separately call `setDate(date)` whenever that value changes.

Comment: @AgonAvdijaj did you get chance to try this?

Comment: Yes thanks a lot, but i went with the transformation method.